# Linq query fails with JSON columns in EF Core 7

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am storing an array in a column in SQL Server and then using `OpenJson()` method to query them with EF Core.

Recently I came across JSON columns introduced with EF Core 7 and decided to give it a try but a simple Linq query fails for a list.

Googling the issue lead me to this link https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/entity-framework-core-7-filtering-on-json-arrays
which shows the exact same query and an exact same error i.e:

```
var results = await db.Posts
                      .Where(x => x.Tags.Any(t => t.Value == "CSharp"))
                      .ToListAsync();
```

Error:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(p => EF.Property<List>(p, "Tags")
> .AsQueryable()
> .Any(o => o.Value == "CSharp"))'
> could not be translated.
> Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

Inserting data and fetching the whole row works fine. So is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: Should probably file a bug on the GitHub repo for EF Core. What's wrong with the workaround in that article? Or what about `from p in db.Posts from t in p.Tags where t.Value == "CSharp" group by p select p`

Comment: Tried this query but same issue. Also the workaround is fine. But I've already got an IQueryable based on some other filters and I wanted to use the same IQueryable to filter out records.

Comment: `FromSqlRaw` and `FromSqlInterpolated` return an `IQueryable` which you can add filters to.